# Keeping a reference instead of a pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a class which basically is a text manager. It can draw text and whatnot. I basically want the color and text std::string to only be a constant reference. Would it then be alright to do

```
class TextManager {
const std::string &text;
void draw(const std::string &text) const;
public:
TextManager(const std::string &text)
{
  this->text = text;
}

void someMethod()
{
   draw(text);
}


};
```

I want when the class that owns an instance of TextManager's text changes, the change is reflected in the TextManager.

would I be better off using a pointer?
thanks

Comment: That doesn't compile, right? I wouldn't think you can change a const reference.

Comment: I just wrote this to give an idea of my concept.

Comment: This code is almost certainly not what you want. `TextManager m("asd"); m.someMethod(); // UB`. You should store a `std::string`.

Comment: @GMan I don't want to have to update the string everytime the parent class's string changes though

Comment: @Milo -- What you should do is store a const, but it should be passed as into your constructor as non-const.  That will prevent the behavior GMan described.

Comment: @Milo -- I meant to say it should be stored as a const reference, but passed as a non-const reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code doesn't compile. `this->text = text` doesn't do what you think it does - it's not like Java where assigning a reference is like changing the pointer. `reference = value` will actually invoke the copy operator, so it will copy the value of the rhs to the lhs, either as member-by-member copy or using the `operator=` if it was overridden. Since your `text` is const, you can't do that.

So in this case, you have to use a pointer - references cannot be modified once initialized.

EDIT: Just to explain ways in which you *could* use a reference:

`const std::string &text = yourString;`

or:

```
TextManager(const std::string &textRef)
: text(textRef)
{
}
```

That way, you have a permanent reference to whatever string you have.

Comment: It is possible to initialize a reference being a member of a class. It has to be done in the initialization list of a constructor. An example of such initialization would be much more appropriate, than an example provided in this answer, in my opinion.

Comment: While correct about the line with the assignment, the code shown could still use a reference. It just needs to be modified to initialize the reference in the constructor's initializer list.

Answer (score 5):

If you never need to re-seat the reference (i.e. refer to a different object), then it's fine.  But in my experience, you'll inevitably find out later down the line that you need to be more flexible, in which case a reference is a pain.  It may be better to go with a pointer from the start.

But note that you can only initialise a member variable of reference type in the constructor initialiser list.  (Also, you probably want to declare that constructor as `explicit`).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have sorted out the initialisation (which other comments can help you with), using a reference will let you do what you want. That is, changes to the referenced std::string will affect your class because they are the same std::string.

You can get similar behaviour using std::string const* instead of std::string const&. As Oli brought out, using a pointer is more flexible. Since a pointer can be null and can be updated using a pointer will allow you to define a default constructor and a (probably compiler generated) assignment operator. Which may not be important in this class but likely will be in some other class you will write (eg if you want to put objects of this class into a std::vector). So you probably are better off using a pointer internally. Though you may wish to still pass a reference to the constructor and take the address of it to initialise the member.